# Is it possiple to run a stored procedure automatically without sql sever Agent?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-design

Hello I am using MS SQL Management Studio express 2005 and I need to have a stored procedure to activate daily.

However I do not have SQL agent.

The Managemnet studio will not be opened daily so I can't use a startup script.

Anyone know how to do this without the Agent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use sqlcmd

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

then have that in a batch file and scheduled via windows scheduler

example below

```
sqlcmd -E -S localhost -q "select count(1) from databasename.dbo.tablename"
```

this will connect to sql on the local machine and perform a rowcount on the table in the database

Comment: thank you, how would I start the script off? thank you somuch for your time

Comment: sqlcmd -E -S localhost -q "select count(1) from databasename.dbo.tablename"              -E means a trusted connection (you may need to use -U and -P to give a specific username and password) -S gives the server and -q is the query....please note that case on the switches is important

Comment: Thanks but i have that and I have errors where they are unable to connect and must have dial in enabled, thanks

Comment: is the script running on a remote machine to the sql server? I would recommend running the scripts on a test server (which has sql installed) first. Once you know that the scripts work on the server you can then move them to a remote server and test again.

Comment: im afaid its on the same machine

Comment: can you post the exact error obviosuly removing anything that may be relating to your company. Im just a bit confused with the dial in comment. Does the sql work when you run it manually on the server?

Comment: ok not sure how but i have got round the dial in part its just now saying incorrect server now, in your example, where you put local host is that the sql sever? thanks again

Comment: it is indeed... so if your server is called LIVESERVER then put LIVESERVER instead of localhost

Comment: ok I have done that and seems to be connected then I say '1) exec dbo.TEST 2) go' and then an error saying can not find this

Comment: just put whatever you want run in the quotes. Probably best to create a stored proc on the server and just call that.

Comment: Thank you , i have got it to call the procedure and do what I want, now I am hoping to save this as a batch file so i can use the schelderto run every day , However I have no luck do I need anything special to do this , thanks again

Comment: just save the script as a .bat file and run it via windows scheduler... sorry cant help any further than that.

Comment: thanks have tried but no luck . i will look into it , thbak you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Create a script that does the database call and use Scheduled Tasks to execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a windows scheduled task to run the command line client `osql`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but you can create a stored procedure in master:

```
use master
go
CREATE PROCEDURE DoStuffDaily
AS
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR TIME '00:05' --5 past midnight?
        EXEC <yourdb>.<schema>.<proc>
    END
go
```

Then just mark this stored proc as a startup procedure using [sp_procoption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181720.aspx), and restart SQL Server.

Comment: when you say mark this a statup procedure, does that mean that this will run everytime SQL is started or will thios always be running? thanks

Comment: It will run every time that SQL Server starts - but note that this particular stored procedure never finishes - it just sits waiting for '00:05' each day, and then runs the stored proc that you're wanting to run daily - if your stored proc runs very fast, you might want to add a second `WAITFOR TIME` after the `EXEC`, to make sure it's not run twice on the same day, i.e. `WAITFOR TIME '00:06'` would ensure that.