# Launch stored procedure and continue running it even if disconnected

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asynchronous

I have a database where data is processed in some kind of batches, where each batch may contain even a million records. I am processing data in a console application, and when I'm done with a batch, I mark it as Done (to avoid reading it again in case it does not get deleted), delete it and move on to a next batch.

I have the following simple stored procedure which deletes processed "batches" of data

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteBatch]
(
    @BatchId bigint
)
AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DELETE FROM table1 WHERE BatchId = @BatchId
    DELETE FROM table2 WHERE BatchId = @BatchId
    DELETE FROM table3 WHERE BatchId = @BatchId
COMMIT
RETURN @@Error
```

I am using NHibernate with command timeout value 10 minutes, and the DeleteBatch procedure call times out occasionally.

Actually I don't want to wait for DeleteBatch to complete. I already have marked the batch as Done, so I want to go processing a next batch or maybe even exit my console application, if there are no more pending batches.

I am using Microsoft SQL Express 2012.

**Is there any simple solution to tell the SQL server - "launch DeleteBatch and run it asynchronously even if I disconnect, and I don't even need the result of the procedure"?**

It would also be great if I could set a lower processing priority for DeleteBatch because other queries are more important than DeleteBatch.

Comment: There's nothing built in for Express. for higher editions, Service Broker or an Agent job immediately spring to mind.

Comment: Thanks, it seems, Service Broker is included in Express, but when I look at tutorials, they all seem really complicated. It's hard to find a minimalistic tutorial for launching a stored proc (with just one parameter) from Service Broker.

Comment: According to the [MS Edition Comparison page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx#Programmability), Broker's not in there either. You can do something really ugly and create a stored proc that's running all of the time, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5104336/15498)

Comment: Oh, I see, they say it's client only, so it can communicate only with full-featured editions...

Comment: HAve you considered limiting the batch size to a much smaller number? Ten minutes to do a delete indicates to me that the batch size is way too large.

Comment: Yes, one of those tableX tables contain about a million records which are related to the other tables, so it seems, SQL is also checking foreign keys... I guess, I'll have to split my stored procedure to delete some predefined number of records until they all are deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know much about NHibernate. But if you were or can use ADO.NET in this scenario then you can implement asynchronous database operations easliy using the **SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery** Method  in C#. This method starts the process of asynchronously executing a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure that does not return rows, so that other tasks can run concurrently while the statement is executing.

**EDIT:** If you really want to exit from your console app before the db operation ends then you will have to manually create threads in your code and perform the db operation in those threads. Now when you close your console app these threads would still be alive because Threads created using System.Thread.Thread are foreground threads by default. But having said that it is also important to consider how many threads you will create. In your case you would have to assign 1 thread for each batch. If number of batches is very large then large number of threads would need to be created which would inturn eat a large amount of your CPU resources and would even freeze your OS for a long time.

Another simple solution I could suggest is to insert the BatchIds into some database table. Create an `INSERT TRIGGER` on that table. This trigger would then call a stored proc with BatchId as its parameter and would perform the required tasks.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This would work if I check callbacks when trying to exit. I guess, if I just exit the application without waiting for all async SqlCommands to complete, they would fail.

Answer (score 1):

What if your console application were, instead of trying to delete the batch, just write the batch id into a "BatchIdsToDelete" table. Then, you could use an agent job running every x minutes/seconds or whatever, to delete the top x percent records for a given batch id, and maybe sleeping a little before tackling the next x percent.
Maybe worth having a look at that?

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Express does not have Agents, so essentially I'll have to implement it myself in some kind of another console application... which again leads me to timeout issues. It seems, I'll have to completely disable SQL command timeout to allow it running as long as it takes.

Comment: There's no Agent with Express.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article which explains how to do [reliable asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/), code included. IS based on Service Broker.

the problem with trying to use .NEt async features (like BeginExecute, or task etc) is that the call is unreliable: if the process exits before the procedure completes the execution is canceled in the server as the session is disconnected.

But you need to also look at the task itself, *why* is the deletion taking +10 minutes? is it blocked by contention? are you missing indexes on `BatchId`? Use the [Performance Troubleshooting Flowchart](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/presentations/archive/2008/04/18/troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-2008-performance-and-scalability-flowchart.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but if someone else has this problem use `SQLCMD`. With express you are limited in the number of users (I think 2, but it may have changed since I the last time I did much with express). You can have `sqlcmd`, run queries, stored procedures ...

And you can kick off the `sqlcmd` with Windows Scheduler. A script, an outlook rule ...

I used it to manage like 3 or 4 thousand SQL Server Express instances, with their nightly maintenance scheduled with the Windows Scheduler.

You could also create and run a PowerShell script, it's more versatile and probably a more widely used than `sqlcmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a same thing..

After searching for long time I found the solution
Its d easiest way

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "your connection string";

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connection.ConnectionString);
            builder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;

            SqlConnection newSqlConn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);

            newSqlConn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storeProcedureName, newSqlConn);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(null, null);
```

Comment: And what if your application exits before the stored procedure completes? Doesn't it close the connection and cause abortion of the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally SQLConnection object should take an optional parameter / property, URL of a web service, be that WCF or WebApi, or something yet to be named, and if the user wishes to, notify user of execution advance and / or completion status by calling this URL with well known message.

Theoretically DBConnection is extensible object one is free to implement. However, it will take some review of what really can be and needs to be done, before this approach can be said feasible.

Comment: Remus, PDW does not have SQL Server Broker. And any context change is very expensive due to the way DSM re - assesses environment.

Comment: What was lost in translation, but needs to be remembered, is that at a present time database connection is an object completely owned by the issuer of the call into database. The irony cannot be lost more then attendant implementation. Where anyone with more than mere beginner level of understanding of involved technologies, knows full well that server carries lion share of resource allocation task, including channel kept by listener for the duration of call and pipeline(s) fulfilling the request. I was hoping to be thoroughly beaten for the half - baked proposal, but didn't hear back a word.

Comment: Even more important is the fact that in the age of paid for distributed compute model of interactions between parties involved in creation, procurement, transmission, retention and retrieval of digital artefacts, the ability to disassociate process of issuing call, producing output, storing output, and than retrieving the output, can potentially represent a distinct business opportunity with RDBMS engine being in the heart of this architecture.
The tricky part is current implementation incapable of supporting it. So, there is a gap in the platform that needs to be fulfilled.